# Get hashtag posts with specific user

Tags: php, twitter

I want to get tweets with a specific hashtag with a specific user. I used
this request to that. But it's not working. But its working without but in the documentation, they said this is working.

```
    <?php


require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ * */
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""
);

/** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); * */
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$hashtag = 'zkst';
$getfield = '?q=from%3Ajulia44K%20%23' . $hashtag . '&result_type=mixed&include_entities=true&count=20';

// Perform the request
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$json_output = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
        ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
        ->performRequest();

// Let's calculate how many results we got
$json = json_decode($json_output);
$n = count($json->statuses);
echo $n;

?>
```

Comment: "_But it's not working._" What does that mean? Do you get tweets from a different user? White page? Tweets from a different hashtag? Any errors when you enable error_reporting?

Comment: no its working like this $getfield = '?q=%23' . $hashtag . '&result_type=mixed&include_entities=true&count=20';

Comment: As per documentation the said this 
When you want the most popular tweets of a specific user using a hashtag:

You want: popular Tweets from @Cmdr_Hadfield mentioning the hashtag #nasa

Your search URL is: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3ACmdr_Hadfield%20%23nasa&result_type=popular

twurl /1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3ACmdr_Hadfield%20%23nasa&result_type=popular